# Why do my array doesn't contains all my values when i'm initializing it in a loop?

Tags: arrays, bash, date

actually i want to get an array of dates, and in a if statement, i'm setting the i elements of my  array to the dates i validated with my if condition.

```
ls muonic_data|(while read line; do
    myYears[i]=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d '-')
    myMonths[i]=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d '-')
    myDays[i]=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d '_' | cut -f3 -d '-')
    myDate=${myYears[i]}-${myMonths[i]}-${myDays[i]
    echo "Mes dates : " $myDate
    if [[ $myDate =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]];
    then  
            myTab[i]=$myDate
            echo $myTab
    fi

done
echo "Mon tableau : "${myTab[*]}
expect recupFileName.exp ${myTab[@]}
)
```

When i run echo at the end of the script, it display me only my lastest date, and not an array of dates. I'm really confused there.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./recupFileName.sh
Mes dates :  2017-11-30
2017-11-30
Mes dates :  2017-11-30
2017-11-30
Mes dates :  2018-03-07
2018-03-07
Mes dates :  2018-04-13
2018-04-13
Mes dates :  2018-05-02
2018-05-02
Mes dates :  2018-3-7
Mes dates :  2018-4-13
Mes dates :  2018-5-2
Mon tableau : 2018-05-02
```

So how can i do to get my date array ?

Comment: You never increment `i`, so you're always assigning the same array index during each loop.

Comment: What do the names of the files in `muonic_data` look like? There is a *much* simpler way to write this loop.

Comment: the different files look like this :
2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1  2018-05-02_11-19-37_R_HOURS_Q1
2017-11-30_15-10-44_R_8294418.33_Q1  2018-3-7_9-30-57_P_HOURS_Q1
2018-03-07_09-30-57_R_HOURS_Q1      2018-4-13_13-23-25_P_HOURS_Q1
2018-04-13_13-23-25_R_HOURS_Q1      2018-5-2_11-19-37_P_HOURS_Q1

Comment: And i want to get the YYYY-MM-DD of each file so i can send it to a .exp file and then do a scp on this files

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ls muonic_data|(while read line; do
myYears[i]=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d '-')
myMonths[i]=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d '-')
myDays[i]=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d '_' | cut -f3 -d '-')
myDate=${myYears[i]}-${myMonths[i]}-${myDays[i]
echo "Mes dates : " $myDate
var myTab = [];
if [[ $myDate =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]];
then  
        myTab[i]=
        myTab.push("$myDate");
        echo $myTab
fi

done
echo "Mon tableau : printf '%s ' "${myTab[@]}"
expect recupFileName.exp ${myTab[@]}
)
```

Comment: It does not work... :/ itś not a display problem, it's my array wich is not adding my elements to the list

Comment: ./recupFileName.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `"$myDate"'
./recupFileName.sh: line 15: `  myTab.push("$myDate");'